# Django - How to pass a User object to a form in views.py

Tags: python, django

I am new to django, and have been tying to pass a User object to a ModelForm and then validate it. That is adding the User object as a ForeignKey to a Note object in the end, where the ModelForm is a Meta of the class Note.

My forms.py:

```
  class NoteForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Note
```

My views.py:

```
  def addNote(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['user'])
        model_form = NoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user)
        if model_form.is_valid():
           model_form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
        return HttpResponse('De indtastede data er ikke gyldige')
     return render(request, 'studies/uploadfile.html')
```

My template.html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/notes/add/">
Note Title: <input type="text" name="name"  /> <br />
Select Note: <input type="file" name="note" /> <br /> 
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ user.id }}">
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
{% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

I have tried using the request.user, since im trying to get the current user logged on and adding that user as the ForreignKey.
Any help will be appreciated, beforehand thanks.

Comment: If you want the current logged in user in your templates, you can use `request.user` right? What is the problem in using it?

Comment: You can, but when i add the user to my ModelForm it won't validate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure what the point is of wanting to send it to the template. You have it in the view both before and after validation, after all: better to deal with it there.

The thing to do is to exclude the `user` field from the form definition, then set it manually on save:

```
class NoteForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Note
      exclude = ('user',)


if request.method == 'POST':
   model_form = NoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
   if model_form.is_valid():
       note = model_form.save(commit=True)
       note.user = request.user
       note.save()
       return...
```

Also note that your view never sends any validation errors to the template, and your template doesn't show errors or the invalid values that the user has entered. Please follow the structure set out in the documentation.

Comment: I don't want to send anything to the template, but from the template to the view. Where i want to add a new object of Note. Trying ur corrections still makes it fail at the model_form.is_valid() and i get the "return HttpResponse('De indtastede data er ikke gyldige')" executed.

Comment: @AndersBækvang If it worked for you, then accept the answer so that it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the save method of the form,

```
def save(self, user):
    note = super(NoteForm, self)
    note.user = user
    note.save()
    return note
```

Also your view must be in this structure:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def contact(request):
     if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            # note: NoteForm.save(request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/') # Redirect after POST
    else:
        form = ContactForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

(copied from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Answer (score 0):

Look here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext

Comment: My problem is, that the form won't validate, when i give it my User object for some reason.